# How would you DRY out this Postgres query to calculate task completion rate?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table of tasks. They have a property called `completed`. I would like to figure out what proportion of tasks in a certain date range have been completed.

Here's a window of tasks I'd like to analyse:

```sql
SELECT * from tasks 
WHERE created_at > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '15 day' 
AND created_at < CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '5 day'
```

#### The rather clumsy approach I have so far

It's embarassing that I can't think of a smarter approach than this but for now this is all I have:

```sql
-- Calculate completion rate: completed / total

-- completed tasks
SELECT (
  SELECT COUNT(*) from tasks 
  WHERE created_at > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '15 day' 
  AND created_at < CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '5 day' 
  AND completed = true
)

-- / total tasks
/ SELECT (
  SELECT COUNT(*) from tasks 
  WHERE created_at > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '15 day' 
  AND created_at < CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '5 day' 
)
```

How would I DRY this query out? I read up on the principle of creating a temporary view but that seems to be overkill for what's needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is basically your query (DRY-ed, half of it) that uses aggregation with [FILTER](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES).

```sql
select
    (count(*) FILTER (where completed))::numeric / count(*) as completion_rate
from tasks 
where created_at > current_date - interval '15 day' 
  and created_at < current_date - interval '5 day';
```

Comment: I'm happy to delete my answer if you add `::float` to the first `count()` otherwise it'll be 0 always :-) you was 8 seconds faster initially, so this is yours!

Comment: You are absolutely right. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `SUM` with a conditional operator to sum either 0 or 1 for the Completed=true and then just a count on the total records as the 2nd column. `

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN completed THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Completed, COUNT(*) Total
from tasks 
WHERE created_at > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '15 day' 
AND created_at < CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '5 day'
```

Comment: I never use postgresql so there could be a syntax error in my code above.

Comment: Looks good according to PostgreSQL's syntax. I would simplify `completed = true` to just `completed`.

Comment: Thank you. This answer worked perfectly and opened my eyes to using case statements inside sum. I gave it to @stefanov.sm's answer though as it also included the ratio calculation